# How to count words in specific columns for multiple files?

Tags: perl, counting, cpu-word

I'm new to Perl and must change an existing Perl script. I need to be able to count all the '500' in columns 1-3 in an entire file before moving on to the next command for that file, and then the next file.  I can have multiple input files. I'm guessing the start would be something like this:

```
@files = <*INPUTFILENAMES>;

foreach $file (@files) {

   open (DATA,$file);

   then do the counts here}
```

Comment: Well, that looks like pretty awful code. None of the variables are declared. Is `strict` mode not enabled? Using bareword filehandles and 2-arg open has been obsolete since 2000 with the release of perl 5.6. `DATA` is also a special handle and you probably shouldn't touch it. Ignoring errors from `open` is a bad idea.

Comment: What to you call "columns 1-3" ? Please update your question with an example of file content and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

No need to mess around opening filehandles. The `<>` operator will give you all of the lines from the files passed on the command line. So your code can look something like this:

```
#/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $count;

while (<>) {
  $_ = truncate_to_three_cols($_);

  # Increment count if the record contains "500"
  # Note: \b marks a word boundary. This means we only
  # match "500" on its own. Not 1500 or 5000, etc.
  $count++ if /\b500\b/;
}

say "I got $count 500s";
```

The hard part is writing the `truncate_to_three_cols()` function. We can't really help here as you give us no hint about the format of your input file. So, this is just an example, assuming you have a tab-separated file.

```
sub truncate_to_three_cols {
  my ($row) = @_;

  # Split on tabs
  # Take the first three columns
  # Join with tabs
  return join "\t", (split /\t/, $line)[0 .. 2];
}
```